# AS3 'with' and 'removeChild' syntax

Tags: actionscript-3

With the following code..

```
var testContainer = new Sprite();
addChild(testContainer);

var testSprite = new Sprite();
testSprite.name = "sim":
testContainer.addChild(testSprite);
```

I'm a little confused as to why the following call returns a child-null error:

```
testContainer.removeChild(getChildByName("sim"));
```

Yet the following code does not, and in fact works exactly as intended:

```
with(testContainer)
{
  removeChild(getChildByName("sim"));
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this as I assumed when you're not casting a reference using `with` it simply prefixes any function calls you supply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call removeChild from the container like below.   `testContainer.removeChild(testContainer.getChildByName("sim"));`

Comment: Apologies I'd made a typo in my question, you still hit the nail on the head though, I need to prefix `getChildByName` with the parent object as well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose implementation you could use as top level method:

```
function removeChildFromParent(d:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
  if (!d || !d.parent) return d;

  return d.parent.removeChild(d);
}
```